# ImageView caption in a bottom-aligned LinearLayout TextView not showing up

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a requirement to realize a certain type of layout. These layout contains an ImageView that is part of the item layout for an horizontal RecyclerView that displays the movies that belong to a particular category.

[Desired layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lfUk.png)

[My current layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaWwv.png)

> The item layout for the RecyclerView containing the ImageView and
>   TextView label.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMediaThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/clientMediaThumbnailLabel"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Movie Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Remove `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: I will try this and revert. Thanks a lot @AmjadKhan

Comment: @AmjadKhan, this didn't work. I had my images shrink and had the white background of the parent LinearLayout showing without the TextView caption showing up.

Comment: What is the size of the image you are loading into it is it in rectangle shape or square

Comment: It is a portait image - rectangular with the height larger than the width. I am also loading it from an endpoint using Picasso. My aim is to ensure it fills the ImageView without any spaces left. However, it seems to be filling up the parent linear layout while obscuring the TextView.

Comment: Try Remove the linear layout and make TextView width wrap_content and you can set layout_gravity bottom and background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to arrive at a solution through setting a layout bottom margin of 20dp for the Image View while reducing the text size of the TextView (to avoid it showing a parent layout right margin space wider than the image).

Adding the bottom margin of 20dp to the image view made the text view's text to become visible.

Here is my updated layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/clientMediaThumbnailLabel"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMediaThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@mipmap/placeholder_image"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Movie Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movieImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/movieTitle" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/movieTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="right"  />


</LinearLayout>
```